# Почему Лермонтов допустил неточную рифму в стихотворении "Парус"?

Tags: поэзия, рифма

Белеет парус одиноКИЙ
В тумане моря голубом.
Что ищет он в стране далеКОЙ,
Что кинул он в краю родном?

В поэзии XIX века неточные рифмы были редкостью, у Лермонтова же я не нашел ни одного случая, кроме этого... Или здесь что-то не так?

Comment: _Правильно: Белеет парус одинокОЙ_... См. http://ilibrary.ru/text/998/p.1/index.html

Comment: @slava1947 - это спорно, как правильно написать в современном издании. Во-первых, надо знать, что было в автографе, во-вторых, орфография оригинала может меняться в связи с появлением новых общих правил и подходов. Но что безусловно правтльно - так это то, что произносить надо именно одинокОй. А не редуцировать "далекой" до "далёкый", как предлагает Г.А.,

Comment: _@Мимоходов: Во-первых, надо знать, что было в автографе..._  Когда-то я принимал участие в обсуждении приведённого в этой теме вопроса. Одним из участников обсуждения был приведён автограф Лермонтова. См. здесь: https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=8183&p=111666&hilit=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81#p111666

Comment: @slava1947 Так а чего его искать-то у "участников"? Он в Вики есть. В нескольких вариантах. Но там остаётся только догадываться, ничего не разглядеть. Я его только разве что под электронный микроскоп не пропускал. У вашего соучастника обсуждения - не лучше.

Comment: @slava1947 если все-таки хотите обсудить разговор по вашей ссылке вообще, то чуть позже. У меня еще есть ссылка на автограф из письма Лопухиной - там нет зачеркнутого "отдаленный" (оно-то очевидно Ы), но "одинокiй" просматривается лучше. Найду - дам знать

Answer (score 3):

Всё так; и рифма у Лермонтова точная.

"Одинокий" произносилось как *одинок[а/ы]й*, что рифмовалось с *далёк[а/ы]й.*

**[Парус](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81_(%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2))**

Белеет парус одинокой

В тумане моря голубом!..

Что ищет он в стране далекой?

Что кинул он в краю родном?..

---

Играют волны — ветер свищет,

И мачта гнется и скрыпит...

Увы! он счастия не ищет,

И не от счастия бежит!

---

Под ним струя светлей лазури,

Над ним луч солнца золотой...

А он, мятежный, просит бури,

Как будто в бурях есть покой!

1832

(Воспроизведено по автографу)

---

> ...Младшие школьники привыкли к вариантам «одинокий» и «скрипит», но
>   учащиеся старших классов должны видеть здесь подлинно лермонтовское
>   написание слов, а точнее – знать, как они произносились. Ученики
>   должны ощущать временную дистанцию, понимать, что это стихотворение –
>   часть другой эпохи, иного мира. Между прочим, такого мира, где
>   возможны грамматические ошибки в молодом литературном языке (у того же
>   Лермонтова читаем: «Из пламя и света // Рожденное слово»), но
>   избегается поэтическая неаккуратность, наподобие неточной рифмы
>   «одинокий – далекой».

**[источник](http://www.poezia.ru/works/116776)**

Answer (score 3):

Я немножко издалека начну. Выбор варианта прилагательного ***ий/ый - ой*** в зависимости от места ударения - это фонетическая тенденция сравнительно недавняя.

Во времена Лермонтова подобные рифмы не считались неточными. Наоборот, это был высокий стиль, подчеркивающий "высокое", "благородное" произношение "парус одинок**ой**" - конечный дифтонг безударный, но с О. Редуцирование О в И/Ы произошло, видимо, незадолго до Лермонтова, в середине XVII в., но в высоком стиле это произношение (известное сейчас как старомосковское) сохранялось еще довольно долго.

Более раннюю традицию можно проследить, например, на фамилиях (их произношение ничем не отличается от собственно прилагательных). 
Толстой (Лев) и некий "толстый" отличаются всего лишь местом ударения. Именно так, Т**о**лстым, был прозван предок (в одиннадцатом поколении) первого графа Толстого (Петра) **Андрей Толстый**, смещение ударения сделано просто с целью "облагораживания" фамилии. Но почему ж тогда графы стали носить фамилию Толст**о**й а не Толст**ы**й? Да просто потому что и предки графов произносили свою фамилию как Т**о**лстой.

Сравните у Пушкина:

*В свою деревню в ту же пору

Помещик новый прискакал

И столь же строгому разбору

В соседстве повод подавал:

По имени Владимир Ленской,

С душою прямо геттингенской,

Красавец, в полном цвете лет,

Поклонник Канта и поэт.*

Здесь Пушкин даже не стесняется писать Ленский через ОЙ.

Если всё ещё неубедительно, то ещё Пушкин.

*Не пой красавица при мне

Ты песен Грузии печальной

Напоминают мне оне

Другую жизнь и берег дальный.*

Здесь, в отличие от строк Лермонтова, трудно сослаться на современное редуцированное произношение "печальнЪй", Только фонетическая замена -НЫЙ на -НОЙ приводит к законной рифме.

*Хотел еще примеры найти из более ранних (Державина-Ломоносова), но что-то сил не хватило. А наверняка есть там. Это системная рифма, не исключение.*

Answer (score 2):

Рифма, безусловно, здесь  точная. Нормы московского произношения в поэзии XIX века соблюдались достаточно последовательно. В соответствии с этими нормами  заднеязычные [г] [к] [х] перед окончаниями прилагательных на -ий не смягчались, произносились твердо: строг[ъ]й, тих[ъ]й, и, соответственно, одинок[ъ]й. На это надо обязательно обращать внимание учащихся при изучении данного стихотворения в школе. Это также прекрасный иллюстративный материал, повод для раскрытия особенностей московского произношения.

Comment: Да то, что они заднеязычные не смягчались - это небольшой секрет, но ЫЙ с ОЙ, даже безударные, все равно не рифмуется, если это не прилагательное им. п., м.р.